# Storing file on Jenkins (not in credentials)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to store a .csv or .txt file and access it from the Jenkinsfile. I currently have couple of files which are in the credential storage (logins, passwords and so on) but this file just has to be stored on the Jenkins machine. I know I could upload it directly to the node but I would prefer doing it in the similar fashion as with the credentials (using web interface).

Comment: have you had time to check my answer below ?

Comment: @MostafaHussein I will check next week, if it works I will mark as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the file in *Managed Files* through the web interface: **Manage Jenkins** > **Managed files** > **Add a new Config**.

Each file saved there will have an auto generated ID or you can set your own id, next you can use [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) to access your files through Jenkins Pipeline using the file ID like this:

```
configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'maven-settings', targetLocation: '/path/to/file/in/workspace')]) {}
```